# Can I manually slot an input neuron into a hidden layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN and I want to sneak in some extra information into one of the final layers.

Here's a simplified version of the code. Watch for the comment

```
def define_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    # this next layer is where I want to sneak the neuron(s) in
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(Dropout(rate=0.4))
    model.add(Dense(168))
    model.compile()
    return model
```

So I have some additional information about the input image which might be able to help the network. Think of it as a clue which may or may not deserve a reasonable amount of weighting.

The clue is in the form of an integer which technically is in [0, inf) but practically is probably in [0, 20].

**So my questions are**

1. What's the appropriate way to represent that hint speaking in terms of NN architecture in general.
2. How do I tweak the Keras model to make that happen in practice?
3. Bonus: If I wanted to, could I prevent the subsequent dropout from ever dropping out this added feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work by using Keras' functional API:

```
def define_model():
    inputs = Input(input_shape=(...))
    hints = Input(input_shape=(...))

    x = Conv2D(32, (3,3))(inputs)
    x = Conv2D(32, (3,3))(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3,3))(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3,3))(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)

    x = Add()([x, hints])

    x = Dense(1024)(x)
    x = Dropout(rate=0.4)(x)
    outputs = Dense(168)(x)

    model = Model([inputs, hints], outputs)

    model.compile()
    return model
```

I don't know about protecting it from the dropout using Keras though.

Comment: Nice and thanks a lot! Do you have any ideas on the representation of my integer hint? Note that the previous layer was put through Relu activation. And also that hint=0 is just as meaningful as hint=16 (so I'm not sure if representing a 0 with 0 activation will actually add any value).

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do with your hints, but a good way to represent an integer from a finite domain (i.e. `[0, 20]`) is to feed it as a categorical vector.

Comment: is there a way of also indicating that the ith element of hints needs to be used to correspond to the ith input sample?

Comment: You want to feed `n` samples to your network along with `n` hints and want the `ith` element of your hints to correspond to the `ith` input?

Comment: Exactly. The inputs are images. And I believe that certain properties of those image (which are easy to get with classical computer vision techniques) can play a big role in helping classify the images. So I pre-process the images with said classical techniques to extract the hints. So for each image, I want to give the CNN the hint I extracted from the particular image. My hypothesis is that it will improve performance of the CNN in most cases.

Comment: But, every hint would be about the image currently fed to the network? I understood this was not the case, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Exactly, every hint would be about the current image. I just realised, maybe what you're doing in your code is already doing what I want it to...

Comment: That's what I think also ;)